# How to make all cells into edit mode in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How can I make all cells in the row to go into edit mode when the user edits a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `DataGrid.BeginningEdit` event and iterate over each row/cell and set the `IsEditing` property to true.

Comment: For iterating over each cell, how would you get a `Cell` object (i.e. `DataGridCell`) of the selected row?